# open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/Ip/Up" failed

Tags: docker, nginx, digital-ocean

I was trying out running a nginx docker container on a digital ocean ubuntu droplet with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8080:80 --name test-nginx nginx
```

When I visit the server with my phone, it works. But when visit from a public wifi network, it failed with a message:

*Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding*

And the droplet terminal logs:

```
2018/11/28 20:46:13 [error] 6#6: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/Ip/Up" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 61.176.223.98, server: localhost, request: "GET http://47.99.121.32:39169/Ip/Up?Ip=128.199.224.125&Port=8080&Check=73&Order=61.176.223.98 HTTP/1.1", host: "47.99.121.32:39169"
61.176.223.98 - - [28/Nov/2018:20:46:13 +0000] "GET http://47.99.121.32:39169/Ip/Up?Ip=128.199.224.125&Port=8080&Check=73&Order=61.176.223.98 HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0" "-"
```

My guess is maybe the public wifi I am using has some restrictions for visiting sources using port 8080 (i.e. any ports other than 80)?

-------ADD-------

The above log only showed up twice and I cannot reproduce it afterwards.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question

Answer (score 0):

The log `"GET http://47.99.121.32:39169/Ip/Up?Ip=<your_ip>&Port=8080&Check=73&Order=61.176.223.98 HTTP/1.1"`is very suspicious.

Someone is doing a brute force cross-site scripting attack. Ref: https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/47.99.121.32

That's probably due to your insure public wifi, asking the question on https://security.stackexchange.com/ may give you better answer.